# Only show active windows in the current space in Mac OSX when pressing CMD-Tab

Tags: mac

I'm new to Mac and have the following wish:

I would like to have one instance of an application (app1) on space1 and another application (app2) on space2. When I pres press CMD-Tab I see every open programs in every space. For example I'm in space1 and press CMD-Tab then I can switch between app1 and app2. But I would like to see only app1 when I'm in space1 and no app2 when I'm in space1.

Is there some setting where I can change this behavior?

Thanks for your help.

Matthias

Comment: I spent a lot of time looking for this answer 18 months ago without success - something tells me there's still not a built-in way to do this.

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @baraboom Hope that if I can get an answer and let you know then. @Paul R I posted the question there.

Comment: You can use *Move focus to active or next window* to cycle through windows in the current space.